# mediaelement.js autoplay doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm using [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation) to display a video. I'm using this code:

```
<body>
<video id="player1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" preload="auto" autoplay="true" src="video.mp4"/>

<script>
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
        features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'fullscreen'],
    });

    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('player1');
    player.play();
</script>
</body>
```

When the page loads, I'd like to automatically start the video. This works fine in desktop browsers, however, in mobile browsers the video doesn't automatically play.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you now need a user-initialized event to play() media on mobile. you can use a clear div to trick the user into touching it to chain up a click() event into a play() call, but can't play() without the user touching _something_

Answer (score -1):

Just put `autoplay muted` like this:

`<video id="video" class="video" autoplay muted />`

It will activate autoplay for every video.